# Are new DHCP options sent automatically to clients?

Tags: dhcp

When new DHCP options are configured on a DHCP server (Like NTP and DNS server options) are these sent out to clients automatically?

if clients were provided an infinite lease time and so they would never encounter the DHCP renew lease 50% mark, how do they discover any changes to DHCP server, if they have no reason to request any information from the DHCP server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When new DHCP options are configured on a DHCP server (Like NTP and DNS server options) are these sent out to clients automatically?

Somewhat. When a DHCP client renews its lease (with the first attempt after half its lease time) the new options are passed to it. With infinite lease time (why would anyone do that?), they'd never get updated.

Comment: I used an infinite lease before assigning reservations to everything as my network had pretty much the same and rarely few new devices joining. I could do static IP address but I find that DHCP has a lot more functionality besides just providing IP address and a DNS server. But considering what you just said, I'll make a normal lease time.

Comment: @JamesHopwood, rather than an infinite lease time, you could use DHCP reservations so that each device gets the same address every time. That is how you do it for servers, printers, etc., but general PCs can use regular DHCP, which should not change the address as long as the PC is still up because a PC will request to renew the DHCP at half the lease time. Shutting down a PC could result in a different address the next time it comes up.